# BreakIterator ICU - Get byte length of grapheme cluster

Tags: unicode, iterator, icu

When using the BreakIterator from ICU, is there a way to retrieve the byte length (or code unit length) of the grapheme cluster at the nth boundary in the input string? Ideally with the least amount of API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self Answer:

If you know your current index in code-units, then you can use ICU::ubrk_current() to return the the cude unit index most recently returned by ICU::ubrk_next().
See: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ubrk_8h.html#a4f8b67527c5c9d9205a3446506ffeefc

I was mostly confused by the ambiguity in the descriptions of the UBreakIterator methods. However, after contacting ICU support, "Character Index" is equivalent to the code-unit index in this case.

With this information, a simple implementation is as follows:

```
(ubrk_current(m_breakIterator) - currentIndexInCodeUnits) * INTERNAL_ENCODING_BYTE_LENGTH;
```